# Definite article 'the' with the word 'painting' when speaking about crafts

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article, proper-nouns

I'm writing an article about Russian traditional handicrafts, such as Khokhloma, Zhostovo, and Gzhel. I know the names of these styles/techniques do not require any determiner before them when I use them alone (because these are proper names), however, I wonder if I need to put the definite article before them when using these names with the word 'painting.' Is it *Khokhloma painting* or ***the** Knhokhloma painting*, for instance?

P.S.: Khokhloma, Zhostovo, and Gzhel are geographical names (e.g. Gzhel painting comes from the village of Gzhel ).

Comment: Can you give us a complete sentence?  I'm guessing that you do not want an article, but it's very difficult to say without a specific example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you're trying to say:

- "Khokhloma painting" (with no article) would be the name of the technique itself, e.g. "She is a master of Khokhloma painting"
- "a Khokhloma painting" (indefinite article) would refer to some unspecified example of the technique, e.g. "While I was there I bought a Khokhloma painting"
- "the Khokhloma painting" (definite article) would refer to a specific example mentioned elsewhere, e.g. "The Khokhloma painting which I bought was beautiful"
- "the Khokhloma painting" would also be used if there was exactly one such painting in the whole world, rather than a technique, in the same way as [the Bayeux Tapestry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayeux_Tapestry)

There are also two relevant meanings of painting:

- The *concrete noun* (used with an article) is used specifically for flat artworks, typically on canvas, paper, or similar material; the kind which you would put in a frame and hang on the wall.
- The *technique* (used without an article) can also refer to any decoration with paint - for instance, decorating pots, or houses. In that case, it generally refers to the *process*, whereas the *result* might be "paintwork" - so you might say "The Khokhloma paintwork on this pot is very beautiful" (again, using the definite article to refer to a specific example).

Finally, note that the same rules apply to any adjective used in the same way, not just one which comes from a proper name. For instance:

> Claude Monet was a master of *impressionist painting*.
> *An impressionist painting* by Claude Monet was sold recently.
> *The impressionist painting* which was sold fetched a high price.

Comment: Your examples with the articles only work if the object is "a painting" - that is, a piece of art that is hung on the wall. Khokhloma usually decorates household objects, so you'd be more likely to say "While I was there, I bought a Khokhloma-painted bowl [or whatever the object is]."

Comment: @CanadianYankee Thanks, I hadn't even thought of that meaning! Having never heard of the places or their styles, I just assumed the countable form of "painting" was relevant, but a pot would as you say not be "a painting". I've added some notes on that distinction.